# App crashes with received memory Exception in ARC while scrolling the scrollview with out using images

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview

I am Using `UIScrollview` and adding subView to display the message. While scrolling it gives `received memory exception`. I am struggling to find this from 15 days. Please help me to solve this.

To display I am loading 5 messages first time. After scrolling adding the subView according to array count.If it is subView is increased according the message length.If it is long messages,It crashes with `received memory exception`.

This is my code

```
-(void)createView:(float)yAxis
{
   // NSLog(@"Create view %f",yAxis);
    for (UIView * view in backgroundScroll.subviews) {
        if (view.tag == 15) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<[pageMessageArray count];i++)
    {
        UIView *backgrounf_View=[self messageChildElements:yAxis :i];
        [del.msglistViewArray addObject:backgrounf_View];
        UIView *backgrounf_View1= [del.msglistViewArray objectAtIndex:i];

        [backgroundScroll addSubview:backgrounf_View1];

        yAxis=yAxis+oldY_Axis+65;
    }



    CGRect contentRect = CGRectZero;
    for (UIView *view in backgroundScroll.subviews)
    {
        contentRect = CGRectUnion(contentRect, view.frame);
    }

    //UIView *backgrounf_View1= [del.msglistViewArray objectAtIndex:i];

    backgroundScroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(backgroundScroll.frame.size.width, yAxis-10);

    lblPermenentmessage.frame=CGRectMake(30, contentRect.size.height+20,800, 50);
    //LastMessageYaxis=contentRect.size.height+20;
    lblPermenentmessage.text=@"Messages are displayed for 24-48 hours and automatically deleted permanently.";
}

-(UIView *)messageChildElements:(float)yAxis :(int)index
{
   // NSLog(@"Create view %f",yAxis);

    communityObject *objMessage=[del.messageArray objectAtIndex:index];
    UIView *backgrounf_View=nil;
    UITextView *txt_Message=nil;
    UIButton  *btnURL =nil;
    UIButton  *btnAttachment=nil;
    UIButton  *btnDate=nil;
    UIButton  *btnSendBy=nil;

    UIButton  *btnAttachmentName=nil;
    UIButton  *btnSendTo=nil;


    NSString *labelText = objMessage.Message;
    NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:labelText];
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    [paragraphStyle setLineSpacing:8];
    [attributedString addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(0, [labelText length])];

    CGFloat height=[self getNewsize:objMessage.Message :backgroundScroll.frame.size.width-30];

    backgrounf_View=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(26,yAxis,backgroundScroll.frame.size.width-30,height)];

    if([objMessage.inorout isEqualToString:@"out"])
    {
        //ye
        [backgrounf_View setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:251/255.0f green:247/255.0f blue:193/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
        [[backgrounf_View layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        [[backgrounf_View layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:236/255.0f green:237/255.0f blue:178/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor]; 
    }
    else
    {
        //[cell.lblName addTarget:self action:@selector(replayClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [backgrounf_View setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:251/255.0f green:215/255.0f blue:245/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
        [[backgrounf_View layer] setBorderWidth:1.0f];
        [[backgrounf_View layer] setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:226/255.0f green:188/255.0f blue:218/255.0f alpha:1.0f].CGColor];
    }


    // backgrounf_View.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    backgrounf_View.layer.cornerRadius=10;
    //backgrounf_View.tag=15;
    backgrounf_View.clipsToBounds=YES;
    backgrounf_View.tag=objMessage.indexValue;

    txt_Message = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(12, 6, backgroundScroll.frame.size.width-40, height)];
    txt_Message.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    [txt_Message setScrollEnabled:NO];
    [txt_Message setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [txt_Message setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    //txt_Message.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;

    txt_Message.attributedText=attributedString;

    //[txt_Message sizeToFit];

    if([del.device isEqualToString:@"iphone"])
    {
        [txt_Message  setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:17]];
    }
    else
    {
        [txt_Message  setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:21]];
    }

    [backgrounf_View addSubview:txt_Message];
    oldY_Axis=height+20;

    if (objMessage.Link.length>0)
    {
        btnURL = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btnURL.frame = CGRectMake(11,height,backgroundScroll.frame.size.width-100,40);
        [btnURL setTitle:objMessage.Link  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnURL.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        btnURL.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
        // btnURL.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        btnURL.tag=objMessage.indexValue;
        btnURL.titleLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
        btnURL.titleLabel.numberOfLines=2;
        btnURL.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20];
        btnURL.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        [btnURL setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backgrounf_View addSubview:btnURL];

        oldY_Axis=height+btnURL.frame.size.height+20; 
    }

    if (objMessage.Filename.length>0)
    {
        btnAttachment= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btnAttachment.frame = CGRectMake(11, oldY_Axis,40, 40);
        btnAttachment.tag=objMessage.indexValue;

        UIImage *buttonattachment=[UIImage imageNamed:@"attach.png"];
        [btnAttachment setBackgroundImage:buttonattachment forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnAttachment.userInteractionEnabled=YES;

        btnAttachmentName = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        btnAttachmentName.frame = CGRectMake(47,oldY_Axis+5,backgroundScroll.frame.size.width-150,60);
        [btnAttachmentName setTitle:objMessage.Filename  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btnAttachmentName.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
        btnAttachmentName.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
        btnAttachmentName.tag=objMessage.indexValue;


        btnAttachmentName.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:20];
        btnAttachmentName.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
        [btnAttachmentName setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [backgrounf_View addSubview:btnAttachment];
        [backgrounf_View addSubview:btnAttachmentName];

        oldY_Axis=oldY_Axis+btnAttachment.frame.size.height+30;
    }

    btnDate = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btnDate.frame = CGRectMake(11,oldY_Axis,130,30);
    [btnDate setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:",objMessage.Date]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnDate.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    btnDate.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
    btnDate.tag=objMessage.indexValue;
    btnDate.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
    btnDate.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    [btnDate setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:70/255.0f green:70/255.0f blue:70/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backgrounf_View addSubview:btnDate];

    btnSendBy = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btnSendBy.frame = CGRectMake(127,oldY_Axis,backgroundScroll.frame.size.width-50,200);
    [btnSendBy setTitle:objMessage.senderPerson  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnSendBy.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    btnSendBy.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
    btnSendBy.tag=objMessage.indexValue;

    // btnURL.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    //btnSendBy.titleLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
    btnSendBy.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
    btnSendBy.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    [btnSendBy setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:70/255.0f green:70/255.0f blue:70/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backgrounf_View addSubview:btnSendBy];

    btnSendTo = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    btnSendTo.frame = CGRectMake(11,oldY_Axis+25,backgroundScroll.frame.size.width-50,200);
    [btnSendTo setTitle:objMessage.senderPerson  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    btnSendTo.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
    btnSendTo.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentTop;
    // btnURL.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
    //btnSendBy.titleLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeCharacterWrap;
    btnSendTo.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15];
    btnSendTo.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0);
    [btnSendTo setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:70/255.0f green:70/255.0f blue:70/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [backgrounf_View addSubview:btnSendTo];


    NSString *communityName=@"";

    if([del.communityId isEqualToString:@"none"])
    {
        communityName=objMessage.Community;            
        communityName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: ",objMessage.Community];
    }

    //NSLog(@"Group type %@ and %@",objMessage.groupType,del.communityId);
    if([objMessage.groupType isEqualToString:@"Personal"])
    {        
        [btnSendTo setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",communityName,objMessage.Person] forState: UIControlStateNormal];        
    }
    else if([objMessage.groupType isEqualToString:@"Everyone"])
    {        
        [btnSendTo setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",communityName,@"Everyone"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];     
    }
    else
    {        
        [btnSendTo setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",communityName,objMessage.GroupName] forState: UIControlStateNormal];       
    }


    [btnURL addTarget:self action:@selector(getLink:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnAttachmentName addTarget:self action:@selector(fileDowload:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [btnAttachment addTarget:self action:@selector(fileDowload:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    backgrounf_View.frame=CGRectMake(24,yAxis,backgroundScroll.frame.size.width-30,oldY_Axis+55);
    LastMessageYaxis=backgrounf_View.frame.origin.y+backgrounf_View.frame.size.height+10;

    del.RefreshValue=0;
    LastValue=index;

    communityObject *com=[[communityObject alloc]init];
    com.MessageId=nil;
    com.Date=nil;
    com.Message=nil;
    com.Link=nil;
    com.Attachment=nil;
    com.Filename=nil;
    com.attachmentType=nil;
    com.imageSize=nil;
    com.groupType=nil;
    com.Person=nil;
    com.GroupName=nil;   
    com.senderPerson=nil;
    com.Community=nil;
    com.inorout=nil;

    return backgrounf_View;     
}
```

[Sceenshot is added please check.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTdTF.png)

Comment: Maybe you should use a UITableView and benefit from its view recycling feature.

Comment: Have you profiled you app with `Instruments` - Allocations/Zombies tools? That might give you a clue about the memory usage of your application.

Comment: @jorn Buitink I am using the UItableview before but its take time to calculating the height.Its not according my requirement so i removed that. i am implementing this UI

Comment: @Cristik Yeah i am using Instruments i  am getting only memory adress how to find the code using memory adress.please help me to find.

Comment: @JörnBuitink i am using uitableview like this shown below code here also giving memory Exception.

Comment: @Anupama usually you can tell from the Allocations report which objects are created the most

Comment: @Cristik How to check the object from that memory allocation.I am new to this please help me.

Comment: I need to know what you find out with Instruments. Please update the question and add screenshots that show where you identified the problem and I can take a look at that.

Comment: I have added screenshot please check and help me

Answer (score 0):

This bit looks like a mutation of array while enumerating it:

```
  for (UIView * view in backgroundScroll.subviews) {
        if (view.tag == 15) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

There is no wonder why the array doesn't like it. I would crash too :)

BTW: That part where it is storing indexes of array in view's tag seems very wrong.

Comment: If remove also i am getting same error.While scrolliing fast App is crash with received memory exception

Comment: yes. It is possible. I would need to go through the code. But that part of code is a guaranteed crash when processing view with tag 15. I would suggest to put some NSAsserts to critical parts. Especially those where you access arays using indexes. It shouldn't be difficult to find out what is wrong.